# Ruby on Rails API Will not deploy on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. No gem-file found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm presently trying to deploy a Rails API onto Elastic Beanstalk. It will not deploy due to the gemfile not being found. See log out put below:

```
 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0",
    "results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered 
    an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: 
    You didn't include a 'Gemfile' in your source bundle. The deployment 
    didn't install any Ruby gems.","timestamp":1601055941,"severity":"INFO"},
{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1601055944,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

I have tried doing `bundle package` in terminal so the cache gem file is used under `vendor/bundle` and it still doesn't not work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not to ask a dumb question, but you do in fact have a Gemfile in the root of your app, right? And the file is not in `.gitignore`?

Comment: @littleforest Thank you for your reply - I can confirm that I do have a gemfile in the root and that it is not in .gitignore

Comment: And your `Gemfile.lock` is also committed?

Comment: Yeah it is committed

Comment: I managed to get rid of the issue by zipping the folder using terminal. For some reason it would not work if I compressed the folder in finder !

Comment: You should also look into using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI. Then you can use commands like: `eb deploy production`, and it will bundle everything up for you, upload it, and deploy.